# Python requests: using proxy but get connect 'Connection aborted'

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, vpn, socks

1. My vpn works WELL, and can visit google(from China).
2. sock5 Port of my VPN: `1080`
3. But when I run the following code, I get error.

```
import requests
headers = {'user-agent': ''}
proxies = {"http": "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080",'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'}

# url = 'https://www.baidu.com/'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=python' #
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
print("res.status_code:\n",res.status_code)
```

4. if I remove , proxies=proxies, and change the url to baidu it works.

```
...
url = 'https://www.baidu.com/'
# url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=python'
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print("res.status_code:\n",res.status_code)
```

5. the error in 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Try.py", line 17, in <module>
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.22.0-py3.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.22.0-py3.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.22.0-py3.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.22.0-py3.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests-2.22.0-py3.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))
```

from 1 to 4, 1 is contradictory to 4. I don't really know where the problem is. I'd be extremely grateful If someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by substituting `sock5` with `sock5h`